# Excel VBA: Wrong position when copying Shape.Top position between worksheets in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am copying a bunch of shapes and their position between worksheets. One of the shapes, however, does not end up in the correct position.

As quick example:

```
    Dim s As Excel.Shape
    For Each s In Sheets("Intro").Shapes
        s.Copy ' copy shape
        ActiveSheet.Paste ' paste shape
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(s.Name).Top = s.Top ' copy top position
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(s.Name).Left = s.Left ' copy left position
    Next s
```

Adressing the shape and sheet explicitly by name provides the correct outcome:

```
    ' insert logo
    Sheets("Intro").Shapes("Logo").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Logo").Top = Sheets("Intro").Shapes("Logo").Top
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Logo").Left = Sheets("Intro").Shapes("Logo").Left
```

But of course I'd like to know where my loop goes wrong.

In the screenshots below, you can see that the pasted images' vertical positition is lower than the original.

Pasted: [image: pasted]

original: [image: original]

Comment: I use `Dim s As Excel.shape` - is there a functional difference?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the "bad" shape? And the good ones. Both from sheets "Logo" and "Intro".

Comment: @Vityata I added some basic screenshots to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Doesn't help a lot...

Comment: What else would you like to see in the screenshot?

Comment: Well, I was thinking that one of the shapes is somehow visibly different from the others, e.g. somehow I was looking for a hint.

Comment: No, it's really just the vertical position that is wrong, everything else is normal.

Comment: Write `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Shapes(s.Name).Left` and `Debug.Print s.Left` before writing  `ActiveSheet.Shapes("Logo").Top = Sheets("Intro").Shapes("Logo").Top` See how these values differ. Is the whole task is taking place in 2 workbooks or in the same one?